# Fastest way to farm IP (general assumptions inside)

Tags: league-of-legends

Making these very general and valid assumptions, what would be the fastest way to farm IP?

1. Win/Loss ratio for normal games of 50%
2. Co-op vs. AI rewards available
3. Always win vs Co-op vs. AI
4. Average match time on all game modes
   -Dominion Co-op vs AI 15 mins
   -Summnoners Rift Co-op vs AI 25 mins
   -Dominion Normal 22 mins
   -Summoners Rift Normal 40 mins

You can add any other valid assumption or edit the current ones, the core of the question is to find out whats the best way to farm IP under a feasible game condition.

Answer (score 1):

Play ranked games and win. You receive the most %boost modifiers.  You can also buy the IP Boosts with RP.  Also don't forget to play every time your 24hrs renews so you can get the first of the day boost!

Answer (score 1):

A guy wrote a lengthy but fully informative article on this topic. It is on Reign of Gaming found here [IP Farming](http://rog.clgaming.net/blogs/a-different-view/5659-guest-post-how-fast-can-you-farm-dat-ip)

Answer (score -1):

I do believe the fastest way is to just grind out PVP games on dominion or summoner's Rift. Most people do it so tehy get the 150 First win bonus as a Co-op vs AI game, then switch over to PVP.